# Using embedded do.call() in Shiny

Tags: shiny, do.call

I'm trying to use Shiny + ShinyBS to create a collapsible panel whitch contains a bunch of column values per column.
However, I'm having trouble in applying `do.call` correctly (or in the sequence I want).

Source code for `server.R`:

```
require(shiny)
library(lazyeval)
library(shinyBS)

l <- lapply(mtcars, function(x) unique(x))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderUI({    
    col_list <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {
      col <- l[[i]]
      a <- lapply(1:min(length(col), 10), function(j) {
        interp(quote(bsToggleButton(nm,lb)),
               .values=list(nm = paste0(names(l)[i],
                                        '_val_',
                                        j),
                            lb = col[j]))
      })
      pars <- list(inputId = paste0('btng_', 
                                    names(l)[i]), 
                   label = '', value = '', a)
      
      interp(quote(bsCollapsePanel(names(l)[i],
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(4,               
                                            do.call(bsButtonGroup,
                                                    unlist(pars))
                                     )
                                   ),
                                   id = nm, value = val)),
             .values = list(i = i,
                            nm = paste0('test_',i),
                            val = '')
      )
    })
    pars2 <- list(multiple = TRUE,
                  open = "test_1",
                  id = "collapse1", 
                  col_list)
    do.call(bsCollapse, unlist(pars2))
  })
})
```

Source code for ui.R:

```
require(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput('plot')
  )
)
```

The code can NOT run! The problem is `pars` seems to be static, it only contains the value of the first iteration.

Comment: Not currently reproducible, where is the `interp` function from?  It is not base, shiny, or shinybs.

Comment: sorry it comes from lazyeval package, have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the code was still not reproducible as is.  I suspect you had run parts of the provided code within your environment (e.g. the 'pars' object was not found with your provided code on my machine).

Second, I think you have just made your apply statements too complex.  The idea of apply statements is to improve readability of your code as opposed to for loops.  Here you have crammed so much in to the `lapply` statements that it is difficult to parse out anything.

To address this, I broke the components apart into their own `lapply` statements (which is far more approachable now).  What was happening with your previous code is that your `pars` object was taking all the variables from the `a` object.  Once these components were separated, I could easily just alter the `pars` statement to iterate through each `a` element.  This provides the different values for each iteration (i.e. variable).  I have only included the server.R as there is not changes to your ui.R

As a followup to your comments below, you are correct that the `interp` and `quote` arguments are unnecessary (I generally avoid them again for clarity, my personal preference).  As for best practices, I sum it up in one concept 'clarity then performance'.  If you are unsure about your objects then LOOK AT THEM!  Below you will find an updated server.R file.  I have also minimally commented it.  You will also find an example of accessing the `bsGroupButton` values.  You can see it is the **group id** that you must reference.  This should get you started (be sure to add `tableOutput('result')` to your ui.R. I highly recommend you look into the documentation of ShinyBS or at least the [demo page](http://spark.rstudio.com/johnharrison/shinyBS-Demo/).

Concise and annotated server.R

```
require(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

l <- lapply(mtcars,function(x)unique(x))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderUI({    

    # Create your buttons
    a <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i){
      col <- l[[i]]

      lapply(1:min(length(col),10), function(j){
        bsButton(paste0(names(l)[i], '_val_', j), label=col[j], value=col[j])
      })
    })

    # add the additional arguments for your future bsButtonGroup call
    pars <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {
      list(inputId =paste0('btng_',names(l)[i]), label = '', value = '',a[[i]])
    })


    col_list<-lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {

      # separate the components for clarity
      rawButtons <- unlist(pars[i], recursive=F)
      buttons <- do.call(bsButtonGroup, c(rawButtons[[4]], inputId=rawButtons$inputId))

      # collapse the groups into panels
      bsCollapsePanel(title=names(l)[i],
                      buttons, id=paste0('test_',i), value='')
    })

    # Collapse everything, no need for pars2, just add elements in a vector
    do.call(bsCollapse, c(col_list, multiple=TRUE, open="test_1", id="collapse1"))
  })

  output$result<- renderTable({ 

    df <- cbind(c("mpg toggle button", c(deparse(input$btng_mpg))))
    return(df)
    })

})
```

original answer for server.R

```
require(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
require(lazyeval)

l <- lapply(mtcars,function(x)unique(x))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderUI({    


    a <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {
      col <- l[[i]]

      lapply(1:min(length(col),10), function(j) {
        interp(
          quote(bsToggleButton(nm,lb))
          ,.values=list(nm=paste0(names(l)[i],'_val_', j),lb=col[j]))
      })
    })

    pars <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {
      list(inputId =paste0('btng_',names(l)[i]), label = '', value = '',a[[i]])
    })


    col_list<-lapply(1:length(l), function(i) {
      interp(
        quote(
          bsCollapsePanel(names(l)[i],
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(4,               
                                            do.call(bsButtonGroup,unlist(pars[i]))
                                     )
                                   ),
                          id=nm,value=val))
        ,.values=list(i=i,nm=paste0('test_',i),val='')
      )
    })

    pars2 <- list(multiple = TRUE, open = "test_1", id = "collapse1",col_list)
    do.call(bsCollapse,unlist(pars2))
  })
})
```

Comment: you're right, I re-ran my code in a fresh window and pars are not found, I believe it existed before I altered my code for questioning. Can you also comment on the best practice to do such iterations? If you start from scratch, what will be done differently? using interp is my work around, I'm not sure whether it could cause any further problems. I remember the author of Shiny package said in an example "if you're using eval(paste) in generating dynamic UI, probably you're doing in a wrong way"

Comment: One more follow up question, it seems in this way click event are not being triggered by the following (conventional) approach                output$result<- renderText({
    if(is.null(input$mpg_val_1)) return()
    isolate({      
      a <- paste0('btn value: ',input$mpg_val_1)
      print('exec')
    })
  })                        Please add textOutput('result')   in ui.R   I am trying to capture the values for each buttongroup so that I can use the values for data subsetting.

Comment: @XiushiLe, see edits, if you have further questions i suggest opening a separate question.

Comment: I do have a further question for you. I used your initial solution and revised solution as comparison to check whether button selection can be captured, it seems that your revised solution works fine. Here's the link for follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348447/shiny-binding-issue-when-generate-ui-dynamically